# Minha pergunta foi negativada várias vezes, devo removê-la?

Tags: debate, voto-contra

Tenho uma pergunta que recebeu vários pontos negativos, apesar de ser uma pergunta relativamente importante para mim e óbvia. Infelizmente ninguém que negativou se preocupou em comentar o que está de errado ali.

Devo remover esta pergunta? Ou ainda assim é importante para o SO mantê-la por ali?

Comment: É uma questão hipotética? Só para saber mesmo, pois não vi nenhuma pergunta na sua conta.

Comment: A resposta vai depender da pergunta, se ela tem respostas, e se as respostas têm votos.

Comment: @Math Será que não é no SOen e ele tá confundindo as pelotas? Não tenho rep pra ver se ele levou negativo em alguma pergunta, mas todas estão com pontuação positiva (ou zerada)

Comment: @jbueno talvez ele já tenha excluído.

Comment: Qual pergunta, tem como postar o link? Talvez aqui alguém saiba lhe orientar como melhora-la (se for possivel).

Comment: Bem pensado @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @jbueno agora só nos resta esperar um retorno dele.

Comment: Mas você tem como ver no perfil dele, não? Ou é só com o link mesmo? @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @jbueno infelizmente as deletadas só se ele enviar o link :/

Comment: @Math esta é minha primeira pergunta no Meta. Pretendo começar a participar pro aqui. Minha participação efetiva ocorre no SOen

Comment: Certo. Mas eu me referia a pergunta que recebeu vários pontos negativos. Ela realmente existe ou é apenas uma dúvida hipotética que você tem?

Comment: -1 @MarceloBarbosa poste o link da pergunta que foi negativada catzo! :P (Em tempo: é óbvio que a dúvida não é hipotética, já que este tópico começa com "Tenho uma pergunta...")

Comment: Acho que você editou seu último comentário depois que eu li ele, pois se bem me lembro você não falava sobre o SOen. Ok, eu olhei lá mas não vi nenhuma pergunta recente com pontuação negativa (talvez você já tenha removido, não sei). A gente ainda não te respondeu aqui pois a resposta resumidamente seria *"depende"*, por isso insistimos tanto em ver a pergunta em questão para podermos dar uma direção melhor. O fato é que depende de muitos fatores, mas basicamente se você quiser remover a pergunta e o sistema deixar, costuma não haver nada de errado com isso.

Comment: Olá Math, a pergunta já foi removida. Alguma maneira de eu recupera-la para exibila a vocês?

Comment: Então era no SOen Marcelo? Foi removida por você ou por admins? Em tempo: se foi você que removeu, na sua página de perfil (no SOen), entre em "Perguntas", e logo abaixo terá um link "perguntas recentes removidas", e ali você pode ver, agora se foi um admin não sei se estará lá...

Comment: @MarceloBarbosa pode nos passar o link dela que a gente consegue ver.